# Button and Paragraph side-by-side, unresponsive

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox button and a Paragraph side-by-side.

It's inline-block and everything is nice... Look:
[image]

When I turn my view into responsive, it just drops down a line. Like this:
[image]
How do I overcome this issue elegently in CSS without starting build divs around elements and bootstrap the whole deal here? Thanks!

re code; those are 2 columns and both button and paragraph reside in he left column.

> EDITED FOR CODE ADDITION:

```
    <div class="row no-pad">
            <div class="col-xs-6 left-hand-input">

                <!--FORM BEGIN-->
                <form class="form-control-static" action="leadGen.php" method="post">
                    <p>PERSONAL DETAILS</p>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="firstName">FIRST NAME:</label><br>
                    <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text"><br>
                    <label for="email">EMAIL:</label><br>
                    <input name="email" id="email" type="email">

                    <p>SHIPMENT ADDRESS</p>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="address">ADDRESS:</label><br>
                    <input name="address" id="address" type="text"><br>
                    <label for="country">COUNTRY:</label><br>
                    <input name="country" id="country" type="text"><br>
                    <label for="zip">ZIP CODE:</label><br>
                    <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text"><br>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SEND">

                    <p style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: -10px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*Required fields</p><br>
<input checked type="checkbox" id="mailingList"/>
<p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 75%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
Receive exclusive membership deals and offers.</p>
                </form>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: can u give us a fiddle / plnkr ?

Comment: I suggest you make span tag and place checkbox inside of it..

Comment: @NelsonTan a <span> around the button would solve this? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I mean wrap the checkbox and text inside the span. and make it inline block with the button.

Comment: @NelsonTan that isn't working.

Comment: can you fiddle this one??

Comment: Please show us your code or create a fiddle, where we can reproduce your issue and see your research effort. Unless you do, we can only guess. --- Please see the help on how to post good questions!

Comment: edited post and added code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use labels

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value=" id="mailingList">Receive exclusive membership deals and offers.</label>
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o4qgu4gv/2/

You should also consider using col-sm-6 instead of col-xs-6 because it may look nice on an iPhone 4 screen

Answer (score -1):

if it is for the checkbox or any input type tag in particular then a more suitable choice would be to use a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) tag instead of a paragraph.

You could use label with its **for** attribute and it should work fine.

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <input type="checkbox" id="btn"> check  
  <label for="btn">
     this should not shift
  </label>
</div>
```